# Op amp implementation

Tags: electricity

I am currently a 3rd year undergraduate electronic engineering student. I am doing a course in signals and systems and I am struggling with a few concepts regarding Fourier Analysis. The textbook we are using is "Linear Systems and Signals (2nd Edition)" by B.P. Lathi.

I have managed to practice the realisation/implementation of a transfer function (from chapter 4 of Lathi) and I seem to be fine with the DFI and DFII realisations, but I have no idea on how to obtain the implementations using op amps (example 4.22, attached below).

Detailed explanation and steps on how to obtain the op amp form of the given transfer function would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should retract and submit this question to the electrical engineering stack exchange to better receive attention.

Comment: Besides the fact that the EE forum is more appropriate, I think that the question is too open-ended as it now is.

Answer (score 1):

If another realization based on second-order filter functions is allowed (see the last sentence), you simply could split the given transfer function into two functions with the same denominator D(s): **H1=2s/D(s)** and **H2=5/D(s)**. Now you have a bandpass (H1) in series with a lowpass function (H2). In total, this yould be realized with a minimum of two opamps. However, some knowledge about active filter realzations is reqired.

Comment: Sorry - I have to correct myself: Both functions must be, of course, added using another opamp.